# How to match front panel connectors to motherboard pins?

Tags: motherboard, front-panel

While cleaning my CPU one of the front panel pins came out. When I tried to put it back all the pins came out. I don't have a guide to reconnect.

[image: motherboard pins]

[image: front panel connectors]

[image]

In what sequence should I connect them?

Comment: I have HDD led +-, RESET SW, POWER SW, POWER LED SW need to connect on motherboard, were on my motherboard no indicators on f panel there are only codes like R380 I don't knew motherboard name or model.. unable to add any photos

Comment: I am unable to add pictures here getting error that I have no 10 reputation

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DNw9gRD

Comment: Do you have any model information about your motherboard?

Comment: No I don't have any info.  https://imgur.com/a/Brj2845

Comment: Not happening any alternative

Comment: @AshishNavgirey - What do you mean "not happening"?

Comment: F usb 1 and 2 slots at back of card

Comment: @AshishNavgirey - Please provide all relevant information in the question body.  You should get rid of any comment that isn't required.  Information can and will be missed if it remains as a comment.  You should provide another screenshot, which clearly indicates the layout of the pins, in order for the Kamill to update their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout of these pins is printed between the PCI (white) slots. It starts with `HDD_LED` in its lower line. Read the whole scheme and connect the front panel accordingly.

[image: detail]

While connecting `POWER SW` and `RESET SW`, the orientation doesn't matter. With LEDs it does matter. I cannot really see if the scheme specifies +/-. If you connect a LED the other way, it won't work, but there's no risk. Use trials and errors to determine the right orientation.

Comment: Please edit share where to put HDD_LED and water about power sw

Comment: @AshishNavgirey Take a photo of the whole scheme and give me a link to it, so I can proceed.

Comment: Due to this it is asking me to put boot disk